# Code first one to Many relationship

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I have defined one to many relationship like this

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey("ClassB"), Column(Order = 0)]
        public int ClassB_ID { get; set; }
         [Key, Column(Order=1)]
        public string  name { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public virtual ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
     }
    public class ClassB
    {
     [Key]
     public int ID{get;set;}
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public virtual ICollection<ClassA> classAs{get;set;}
    }
```

Works fine until I bind classA to a Listview with Bind(ClassB.Name)

I get The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because of using *Lazy Loading*. Which cause the additional round trip to database when trying to access with navigation property (ClassA), but your context is already disposed.

> *Lazy Loading*: When the entity is first read, related data isn't
>   retrieved. However, the first time you attempt to access a navigation
>   property, the data required for that navigation property is
>   automatically retrieved. This results in multiple queries sent to the
>   database.

You could probably solve this problem with *Eager Loading* `Include()` or *Explicit loading*.

```
var values = context.ClassB.Include("ClassA").ToList()
```

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/maximizing-performance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application